# What is a directive in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've been reading tutorials on ASP.NET MVC and they mention things like "the `@model` directive", etc. What is a directive in ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1):

Any of the `@` prefaced html renderer/helpers in ASP.NET MVC's Razor syntax.

```
@section, @model, @function, @helpers, etc
```

They are more commonly referred to as "helpers", per this [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1803776.aspx?%20directives%20in%20MVC%203).